# Find missing numbers in the sequence and decode the message

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

Find missing numbers in the sequence and decode the message

Sequence - 81, 87, 69, 82, 84, 89, --, --, --, --

Message - 117 110 100 101 102 105 110 101 100 101 116 97 114 116 110 101 39 104 99 32 105 111 118 32 44 97 122 110 97 114 101 112 115 32 105 110 103 111 32 101 116 97 105 99 115 97 76

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step:

> Sequence: ASCII values of QWERTY, which is the English keyboard
>  So the missing values are: 85, 73, 79, 80
>  Then the message is `undefinedetartne'hc iov ,aznareps ingo etaicsaL`

Credit to @`M Oehm`:

> Reversing it leads to `Lasciate ogni speranza, voi ch'entrate`
>  Using google translate: `Leave all hope, you who enter`
>  Or something to do with [Dante](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Dante_Alighieri)'s [Inferno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_(Dante))

Comment: This is what i've been working on, I get undefined as the start of the sequence and then not much else?

Comment: @Jon.G: don't give up your hops: What's after "undefined" is backwards and in Italian.

Comment: (The line is from [Dante's Inferno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_(Dante)), which may be a better reference than Google translate.)